# Windows Form launched from WPF window showing no current system theme. Why?

Tags: wpf, winforms, reflection, assemblies, themes

I have a WPF application that has a variable "x" which is an instance of a class from a custom C# assembly called "MyClasses.dll". This variable "x" has a method "LaunchForm" that launches a Windows Form "Form1" from another assembly "MyForms.dll". The form is launched as a dialog and shown in the screen but the current Windows XP / Win7 theme/skin is not applied to it. If this "Form1" is launched from a Windows Form (not WPF window) it is shown correctly though. Any ideas why this is happening? Any hints to solve this issue?

Cheers all!
Edgar

I just looked at the code again and I'm not using reflection on this way of launching the winform. The code as requested is in WPF:

MyInterface x=new MyClass1();
x.LaunchForm();

The code in MyClasses.dll:

public class MyClass1() : MyInterface
{
public MyClass1()
{}
public void LaunchForm()
{
Form1 Form1Dialog=new Form1();
Form1Dialog.ShowDialog();
}
}

This, as mentioned, launches the winform from WPF but no windows theme is applied to it.

Comment: Can you post the code - it will help in answering.

Comment: Yes, a sample of the code you are using to call the form would help a great deal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you don't have the proper manifest to tell Windows you are compatible with the new theme (WPF doesn't need it).

I wrote about it on my blog at http://www.nbdtech.com/Blog/archive/2008/06/16/The-Application-Manifest-Needed-for-XP-and-Vista-Style-File.aspx

Comment: Nir, thanks for your help. Your article did help to enable the themes in my dialogs. The solution: a manifest had to be added to the application indicating the dependency for Microsoft Windows Controls.